# Truncate multiple columns in PySpark Python

Tags: pyspark

I have a table with multiple columns and only some of these columns need to be truncated down.
For example a text field might go beyond 7 characters and this needs to be reduced.

lets say I have df:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaaaaaaaaa | 12345 | abcdefg | Cell1 |
| bbbbbbbbbb | 12345 | abcdefg | Cell2 |
| cccccccccc | 12345 | abcdefg | Cell3 |
| dddddddddd | 12345 | abcdefg | Cell4 |
| eeeeeeeeee | 12345 | abcdefg | Cell5 |
| ffffffffff | 12345 | abcdefg | Cell6 |
| gggggggggg | 12345 | abcdefg | Cell7 |

I can see that Columns A and C need truncating down to 5 characters.

``col_to_truncate = ['Column A', 'Column C']

df.withColumn('Column A', substring('Column A', 1, 5)).withColumn('Column C', substring('Column C', 1, 5))
``

The code will work but what if I want to process lots of columns dynamically, is my only option using a for loop?
Is it possible to use list comprehension rather than a for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use select instead of withColumn like so:

```
df.select(*[substring(c, 1, 5).alias(c) for c in df.columns])
```